# (jQuery) Add/Remove class to 'a'

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to add/remove the class **.hover** to the link `<a href="#" id="permalink"></a>` when I hover it. But it's not working! Check it out:

**CSS**

```
#content-r #right #post-outer {
 width: 264px;
 height: 264px;
 background: #1f1f1f;
 -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
 -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
 column-break-inside: avoid;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 11px;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: -5px;
 margin-right: 7px;
}

#content-r #right #post-outer a {
 padding: 0px 0px 245px 260px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 997;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 4px;
}

#content-r #right #post-outer .body {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0px 19px 0px 19px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 226px;
 z-index: 997;
}

#content-r #right #post-outer .body .track{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: -20px; 
 position: relative;
}

#content-r #right #post-outer .body .artist{
 font-size: 20px; 
 margin-bottom: -20px; 
 position: relative;
}

#content-r #right #post-outer .body .feat{
 font-size: 15px; 
 line-height: 18px; 
 margin-top: 3px;  
 position: relative;
}

.hover{
 width: 263px; 
 height: 263px; 
 background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/274369538/images/body-hover.png') -1px 0px; 
 position: absolute; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="post-outer">
 <a href="#" id="permalink"></a>
 <div class="body">
   <div class="track">Track here</div>    
   <div class="artist">Artist here</div>
   <div class="feat">Featuring here</div>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <img src="MY-IMAGE-HERE" width="264" height="264">
 </div>
```

I tried to use this jQuery, but it didn't work:

```
$('#permalink').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#post-outer').find('a').addClass('hover');
});
```

Thanks!

*(Here's the link where I'm using those codes: http://www.comocanta.com.br/)*

Comment: Seems to work fine [here](http://jsbin.com/joneziqo/1/)?

Comment: And did you include jQuery, use document.ready etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to remove it when the user moves the mouse away?  In that case you could use:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#permalink').hover(function () {
        $('#post-outer').find('a').addClass('hover');
     }, 
     function () {
        $('#post-outer').find('a').removeClass('hover');
     });
})
```

Comment: It worked! But only on the first image :( (Check it out: http://www.comocanta.com.br/)

Comment: You shouldn't use the same id attribute multiple times. You can give it a class and use that instead.  Once you're doing that, then you could just do as Chris Conway says in another answer and use the `:hover` pseudo-class to get the same effect.  I originally had that as part of my answer, but took it out in case you really wanted the class added for another purpose later.  If it's just for the visual effect then I would use pure CSS.

Comment: Oh, I see! **3abqari** said the same thing down here. I will work on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the ID attributes on this page correctly.  You can't have two elements on a given HTML page with the same ID attribute.  That explains why it's working for the first one only.  Your code needs a little revising.  Maybe use classes instead of IDs... since the class attribute can be the same in two elements in an HTML page.  Let me know!!!

Comment: For example, this pattern is repeated throughout the page... `<div id="post-outer">
    <a href="#" id="permalink" class=""></a>

    <div class="body">
    </div>

    </div>`

Comment: I'll change this! Thaks for all.

Comment: Then what you need to do is maybe change the code to become (let me know if that doesn't work):       `jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.permalink').hover(function () {
        $(this).find(a).addClass('hover');
     }, 
     function () {
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('hover');
     });
})`

Comment: Just replacing $(".post-outer").find('a') with $(this).find('a') makes it specific to that element, instead of being generic to all elements with class "post-outer"

Comment: In this case, when you do $(this).find('a') it now has the <a> element in its context... then you addClass('hover') to the <a> element

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just use pure css to do the trick?

```
#permalink:hover{
    width: 263px;
    height: 263px; 
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/274369538/images/body-hover.png') -1px 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#permalink").on('mouseover',function(){
     $('#post-outer').find('a').addClass('hover');
});
```